# Let $S = [0, 1] × [0, 1]$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: metric-spaces

If $P = (x_1, y_1)$ and $Q = (x_2, y_2)$ are arbitrary points in the plane, define
the metric
$d(P, Q) = max\{|x_1 − x_2|, |y_1 − y_2|\}.$
Let $P = (2,\frac{1}{2})$. Let $S = [0, 1] × [0, 1]$.

Which of the following statements are
true?

$a.$ There does not exist any point $Q ∈ S$ such that
$d(P, Q) = \min\{d(P, X) | X ∈ S\}.$

$b.$ There exists a unique point $Q ∈ S$ such that
$d(P, Q) = \min\{d(P, X) | X ∈ S\}.$

$c.$ There exist infinitely many points $Q ∈ S$ such that
$d(P, Q) = \min\{d(P, X) | X ∈ S\}$

I thinks option $b)$ is correct

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: min{d(P,X)|X∊S} is absolutely = to 1, and there is only one point in S that has that minimum distance ... so (b) is the answer. This isn't really any _theorem_ as such ... I think it's just an exercise in interpreting set-notation correctly.

Comment: The point being (1,1/2).

Comment: Ah no ... alright ... yes if you're not used to set-theoretical notation & not as well-versed it it as you ought to be: it's all the points on the right-hand vertical edge, isn't it! It's coz my mind keeps defaulting to _Euclidean_ distance, and it's difficult to stop it from doing so!

Comment: So (c) then ... that's _why_ we are set these exercises, I suppose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a. is false: $Q = \left(1,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is such a point (the minimum being 1).
b. is false: $Q = \left(1,1\right)$ is such a point (and I have no idea what $f$ is supposed to have to do with anything.
c. is true: $Q = \left(1,x\right)$ is such a point for every $x \in [\frac{-1}{2},1]$.